# Woocommerce How to change default order status for cash on delivery payment gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, woocommerce, status

If you pay an order with cash on delivery (payment gateway cod), woocommerce set the order as "on-hold" status.
I need to set the status for new orders as "pending".

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Manuel

Answer (score 4):

this code will help you put yout logic and changes in the function

```
<?php add_filter (‘woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status’, ‘my_change_status_function’);



 <?php 

 function my_change_status_function ($order_id) {
 $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
  //Do whatever additional logic you like before….
  return ‘completed’;
}

?>
```